# Why calling cancelAllLocalNotifications removes/clears Notification Center?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, notificationcenter

Using `cancelAllLocalNotifications` should basically `cancel the delivery of all scheduled local notifications`. But it goes ahead and clear the history as well, and as a result the Notification Center doesn't show the last 1/5/10 recent items/notifications.

I'm not sure if it's a bug or is this intentional?

Perhaps i should use `cancelLocalNotification:` to cancel only scheduled local notifications (that are scheduled to fire in the future). But will that have an impact on the `64` local notifications limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reported this as a bug to Apple. Maybe it's intentional, and maybe not. I ended up using `cancelLocalNotification:` instead of `cancelAllLocalNotifications`.

Comment: still its not removing the second local notification when we are cancelling local notifications.